# What is $f_\alpha(x) = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{n^\alpha}{n!}x^n$?

Tags: special-functions, power-series

I want to understand the function
$$f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{n^\alpha}{n!}x^n, \ \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$
for any possible real $\alpha\geq0$. I know that for $\alpha$ integer, $f_\alpha(x) = P_\alpha(x)\times e^x$ with $P_\alpha$ a polynomial of degree $\alpha$. The coefficients of the polynomial can be obtained with some combinatorics. Do you have any idea on how to understand the general case?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: A [similar question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161068/has-anyone-seen-this-series), with $n^a$ in the denominator.

Comment: Very interesting, actually. Thank you!

Comment: This function is implemented in mpmath as polyexp(): http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009_03_01_archive.html, and the reference you want is Khristo N. Boyadzhiev's paper /Polyexponentials/: http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1332

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how useful this partial answer is for you, but we could probably use the ideas from [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895480198332594) by Flajolet and Prodinger on generalizing [Dobiński's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DobinskisFormula.html) to complex arguments.

To wit, since

$$\mathscr{B}_k(z)\exp\,z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^k z^n}{n!}$$

where $\mathscr{B}_k(z)$ is the [Bell polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html), and we have the exponential generating function

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mathscr{B}_k(z)}{k!}u^k=\exp((\exp\,u-1)z)$$,

we can then consider applying Cauchy's differentiation formula,

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm dz$$

to the exponential generating function. (Note that $\gamma$ can be an anticlockwise closed contour, or a Hankel contour encircling the negative real axis.)

I'll probably try out a few numerical experiments on this when I get to my own computer.

Comment: Hi, JM! Glad to see you back.

Comment: Hello @Américo, thanks for the greetings. :)