# A generalization of Bell numbers to arbitrary complex arguments

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, special-functions

For $n\in\mathbb N$, the [Bell number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellNumber.html) $B_n$ is a number of ways to partition the integer range $[1,\,n]$ into pairwise disjoint non-empty subsets. E.g. $B_3=5$ because
$${\large\cup\,}\{\{1,2,3\}\}={\large\cup\,}\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}={\large\cup\,}\{\{2\},\{1,3\}\}={\large\cup\,}\{\{3\},\{1,2\}\}={\large\cup\,}\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}.$$
Is there a nice generalization of Bell numbers to arbitary complex arguments, similar to how the number of permuations of $n$ items (factorial) is generalized to the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$?

Comment: Cool question!  What kind of "integers" are you considering in the complex case?  [Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)? [Eisenstein integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer)? Something else?

Comment: I am asking about arbitrary complex numbers, not necessary some sort of "integers".

Comment: See [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula).

Comment: A cute observation is that $e^{e^x-1}$ has coefficients $B_n/n!$ (it's the exponential gen. function of the Bell numbers.) But that doesn't seem like the right generalization: it seems to me we need to find an appropriate  _integral representation_ for the Bell numbers (a la the Gamma function.) In fact, the Mathworld page for the Bell numbers includes one due to Cesaro (a pretty crazy looking one). So that may well be the right expression to start from.

Comment: @Semiclassical BTW, the Cesàro integral representation on _MathWorld_ has several typos ($n$ instead of $i$ in $(16)$, and $t$ instead of $\theta$ in $(17)$).

Comment: That's irritating. Do you have an authoritative source?

Comment: @Semiclassical No. Actually, I only learnt about it today and would like to see a proof of it. I just noticed that after fixing those typos it started to give numerically correct results.

Comment: @Semiclassical Unfortunately, the _Wolfram Function Site_ also contains an incorrect formula: http://functions.wolfram.com/04.23.07.0001.01 I have sent them reports about these errors.

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771284) As I noted in the answer to the other question, one might consider using Cauchy's differentiation formula with an appropriate contour for numerical explorations. This is similar to the approach I made to [generalize the partition numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34942).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, there are several possible generalizations:
1. Dobiński formula:
$$B_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^x}{e\,k!}$$
2. Cesàro integral representation:
$$B_x=\frac{2\,\Gamma(x+1)}{\pi\,e}\int_0^{\pi } \sin (t\,x)\sin \left(e^{\cos t}\sin\sin t\right)e^{e^{\cos t}\cos\sin t}\,dt$$

Interestingly, the results from these two formulae agree only for positive integer $x$, but are different for fractional $x$.

Comment: Are these both convex and/or $\log$-convex over positive rational $x$?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's an interesting question.

Comment: The first one is, I think that makes it the natural generalization of the bell numbers for complex $x$. Curiously its not too different looking than the riemann zeta function, it's like a zeta function with a factorial on the bottom.

Comment: I agree that the first looks more natural. The second one is contrived.

Comment: I wonder what we can say about this complex function now? start with just its zeroes  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431777/has-anyone-characterized-the-zeroes-of-the-bell-numbers

Answer (score 5):

One can use [Ramanujan's master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_master_theorem). As remarked in the comments, we have

$$B(x) := e^{e^x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

The function $F(x) = B(-x)-e^{-1}$ is of rapid decay as $x \to +\infty$, and therefore the integral

$$L(F,s):= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty F(x) x^s \frac{dx}{x}$$

converges for every $s>1$. By a standard argument, we can rewrite this as

$$L(F,s):= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)(1-e^{2\pi i s})}\int_C F(x) x^s \frac{dx}{x}$$

where $C$ is the keyhole contour. The function $L(F,s)$ now makes sense for all complex $s$. At $s=-n$, where $n$ is a positive integer, the residue theorem shows that

$$L(F,-n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big|_{x=0}F(x) = B_n/n.$$

Therefore the function $G(s)=sL(F, -s)$ satisfies $G(n)=B_n$ for every $n>0$.

It would be interesting to see whether this gives the same function as the one suggested by Lucian in the comments!

Comment: It's worth noting that the Bell numbers represent the $t=1$ value of the Bell _polynomials_ with generating function $e^{t(e^x-1)}=\sum_{n=0}\dfrac{B_n(t)}{n!}x^n$. So I would think this argument obtains a generalization of the polynomials as well.